# one CMS for multiple domains under one web host provider?

Tags: content-management-system, shared-hosting, multiple-domains

could anybody recommend free CMS that

- is preferably part of SimpleScripts or could be installed let's say with BlueHost shared hosting environment
- can handle multiple domains using one database/interface/CMS application. Every domain will have similar yet different content. I would like to have list of records in the CMS application that I place rules on based domain name. So one record would be displayed on domain1.com, record2 on domain1.com and domain3 etc etc.
- would be plugin ready
- easy to use,set up,
- reliable, fast to serve user requests
- big community
- did I forget anything? :-)

Comment: If there isn't one, there should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) with [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module handles this task very well.